# How to display list result - searchView

Tags: android, searchview

I want to implement the best way to implement a search. In my Activity I have two tabs with a list results and I have added a searchView in the toolbar where the user can type what he is looking for. is there a way to display a list result above my activity whit the results as in whatsapp?

[image]

Below is the code I have but its basically a searchView.

```
   @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_subs, menu);

        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener(){

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                return false;
            }
        });

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented it using this dependence [MaterialSearchView](https://github.com/MiguelCatalan/MaterialSearchView)

**Step 1**

Add the dependencies to your gradle

```
compile 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'
```

**Step 2**

Add MaterialSearchView to your layout file along with the Toolbar

```
<!— Must be last for right layering display —>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/theme_primary" />

        <com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView
            android:id="@+id/search_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

**Step 3**

Add the search item into the menu file:

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_action_search"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/abc_search_hint"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
```

**Step 4**

Add define it in the onCreateOptionsMenu:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        searchView.setMenuItem(item);

        return true;
    }
```

**Step 5**

Set OnItemClickListener

```
 MaterialSearchView searchView = (MaterialSearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);
searchView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //Do some magic 
            }
        });
```